# question for documentation?

Tags: support, asking-questions, site-definition

Can I ask questions about writing the following types of documentation listed below on Writers SE?

- Requirements
- Architecture/Design
- Technical
- End User
- Marketing

Comment: Yes, questions about technical or scholarly writing are very much on topic here. Did you have certain kinds of questions in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, questions on all of these types of writing are on-topic here.  The questions should be focused on the *writing*, including processes, rather than the *specific technical content*.  For example, "what makes a good system requirement?" isn't on-topic here, but "how do I make my requirements document understandable to all audiences without sacrificing technical rigor?" and "how do I present such-and-such information while following the IEEE format?" are.

Similarly, some of the document types you listed rely on diagrams; questions about that aspect are on-topic if focused on the communication aspects rather than, for example, how to use Visio to make an inheritance diagram.

See also [this answer about API documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158501/162102) on MSO.